# Conjugate vaccines in the context of the original antigenic sin and antibody feedback inhibition

Tags: human-biology, immunology, medicine, vaccine

How come we can get an antibody response against a polysaccharide bound to a carrier protein, that we have antibodies towards, when antibody feedback inhibition exists?

If we have antibodies against the carrier protein then surely this will lead to inhibition of the B-cells that express B-cell receptors for the polysaccharide?

What's going on here?

Comment: Check out [this review](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1365-3083.2006.01818.x). Antibody feedback regulation can go both ways. Downregulation is associated with antigen masking, but that won't happen if the (new) polysaccharide antigen isn't masked by the existing Abs. So, the answer is, it depends.